# Why the emulator is slow in android studio and also Genymotion?

Tags: android, performance, emulation, genymotion

The Genymotion emulators are slow on Android Studio even though I did the tutorials on youtube to make it faster but still doesn't work.

The problem is, my computer is very good enough to make the emulator run super fast.
It's core i7 8th Gen 8850H, 16GB ram, Nvidia 1050.

I expected the emulator to run super fast.

Answer (score 0):

WEll for an other option you can use adb driver to run the apps live on your mobile devices! it also give a better view of orientation of app.

Comment: I don't have device

Comment: try reinstalling android studio and then install genymotion again

Answer (score 0):

there is an option in emulator to use GPU . it will make your emulator significantly fast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change virtualbox system setting like adding for memory etc.